# How to fix Operator '&' is not defined for types 'Date()' and 'Date()'?

Tags: vb.net, monthcalendar

im doing a programming project and have been stumped on how to add more dates to the bolded dates
in a monthly calendar.

```
Private Sub BTN_Submit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTN_Submit.Click
    Dim format As String = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    Dim boldeddates() As Date = FRM_EventsCalendar.MonthCalendar1.BoldedDates()
    Dim dateTime As String = TXT_Date.Text
    Dim dt As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime)
    Dim str As String = dt.ToString(format)
    Dim specialdate() As Date = {str}

    **FRM_EventsCalendar.MonthCalendar1.BoldedDates = specialdate & boldeddates**

    MsgBox("Date Added")
End Sub
```

i am trying to add them together so that instead of replacing the variables they both are bolded.
i have tried "&" and "," however none of these work. i was just wondering how this could be solved?

thx for any help :).

Comment: Set `Option Strict` to `ON` as soon as possible

Comment: I see some inconsistencies in the code. If you are accepting dates from a textbox there is no need to convert that to date then to string back again, you should just validate that the input is in the expected format and act accordingly. To address the question, what is FRM_EventsCalendar.MonthCalendar1.BoldedDates? Is it a list, dictionary, array?
Depending on the type of object it should have a .Add() method to add new members to the collection.

Comment: FRM_EventsCalendar.MonthCalendar1.BoldedDates is a Month Calendar in the toolbox (sorry thats all i know). I'd hoped it worked like a listbox but It doesn't give me an option to use .Add()

Comment: As for the code im just using stuff ive found on here to get a grip on how to use Month calendar as i've never used it before

Answer (score 0):

Use [MonthCalendar.AddBoldedDate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.addboldeddate?view=netframework-4.8.1)

```
FRM_EventsCalendar.MonthCalendar1.AddBoldedDate(specialdate)
```

Comment: Perhaps you might consider adding some detail to your answer rather than just a link?  Links go stale.

Comment: @Hursey - not likely in this case, but...

Comment: Problem Solved, Thank You :).
I tried this at first but missed
    FRM_EventsCalendar.MonthCalendar1.UpdateBoldedDates()